# What is the correct way to have a copyright and revision date in HTML5?

Tags: html, validation, xhtml, meta-tags

I'm migrating web pages to HTML5 (from XHTML 1.1 + RDFa 1.1) and am getting errors where I did not get them before when I attempt to validate the HTML.

In my `head` I have

```
<meta name="revised" content="2104-02-11" />
<meta name="copyright" content="© Rax, all rights reserved." />
```

and now get

> Bad value revised for attribute name on element meta: Keyword revised
>   is not registered.
>
> Bad value copyright for attribute name on element
>   meta: Keyword revised is not registered.

What is the correct way to have a copyright and revision date in HTML5?

---

My document now begins simply

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
```

which is, I gather, what all the cool cats are doing these days.

Comment: http://www.html-5.com/metatags/

Comment: @RobertHarvey: Weird. Why would the validator be rejecting it?

Comment: Don't know.  Does the page really have to be error free?  [Check this out.](http://validator.w3.org/check?uri=http%3A%2F%2Fstackoverflow.com%2Fquestions%2F21710313&charset=%28detect+automatically%29&doctype=Inline&group=0)

Comment: @RobertHarvey: I guess I can survive failing validation. (But I don't want to be doing something that's actually wrong!) Is there another way to express this that might pass; or some resource or specification I can link to that knows about it.

Comment: Read the second answer in the question I linked, which states that these terms will not validate until the validators add them, and the validators won't add them until they become actual standards.

Comment: @RobertHarvey: The question remains: is there a way people put these in `head` currently?

Comment: Look through the Dublin Core, and see if there's something you can use in there (as the first answer in the question I linked states, are you reading these things? :)  Otherwise, I'd live with the errors; you can justify them.

Comment: I wouldn't link to http://www.html-5.com/metatags/ without adding a disclaimer that that site is not an official source of information. For instance, it says that "The `<meta charset="..."/>` tag should no longer be used" which is simply not true.